# Method for analyzing interactions of periodical exposures (drug x drug interaction and likelihood of adverse events)

Tags: time-series, survival, interaction, time-varying-covariate

I am interested in studying drug usage interactions (drug x drug) and its relation to adverse events. I would appreciate help with choosing the right model/method for this type of analysis.

The data is as follows:

- Background information about a subjects (id, age, gender)
- Exposure, i.e. usage periods for separate drugs (start date, end date). A drug can have several usage periods in the data and the
  length of the periods can vary (e.g 1 day or 10 years period)
- Events (date of the event). There can be only one occurance of the event per subject (e.g. death) or several occurances (e.g. arrythmia
  episodes)

As I mentioned, the main interest of the analysis is the interaction of two separate drugs, and the relation of interaction to occurance of the events i.e. if the probability of the event is altered when using both drugs simultaneously (overlapping usage periods) in contrast to what you would expect by just looking at the combined probability of the individual drugs.

It would also be beneficial, if the model could incorporate possible confouding factors such as age, gender etc. as covariates.

I have looked into several different methods, but have had problems finding a suitable one that could account for all the necessary things (interaction, dates, covariates etc.) and therefore would appreciate all help with choosing a suitable method, and also other comments/considerations I should take into account with the analysis.

Mock-up data to illustrate the starting point. Example study question could be "Does the simultaneous use (i.e. interaction) of aspirin and codein alter the likelihood of arrythmia occurance?"

Subjects:

```
subject_id  gender  age 
1           M       42  
2           F       32
```

Events:

```
subject_id  event       event_date
1           arrythmia   01-01-2002
1           arrythmia   02-04-2015
1           death       05-05-2016
```

Drug usage periods:

```
subject_id  drug    start_date  end_date
1           aspirin 02-03-2001  03-04-2001
1           aspirin 05-05-2001  02-01-2002
1           codein  01-01-2008  02-02-2008
2           aspirin 10-11-2005  04-08-2006
```

Comment: This is pretty broad. Can you make it narrower & more concrete than 'help me choose a suitable method, and what other considerations should I take into account'?